# How to fix org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException while changing the order of columns in a dataframe?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am trying to load data from an RDBMS table on Postgres to Hive table on HDFS.

```
      val yearDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url", connectionUrl)
                        .option("dbtable", s"(${query}) as year2017")
                        .option("user", devUserName).option("password", devPassword)
                        .option("numPartitions",15).load()
```

The Hive table is dynamically partitioned based on two columns: `source_system_name,period_year`
I have these column names present in a metadata table: `metatables`

```
val spColsDF = spark.read.format("jdbc").option("url",hiveMetaConURL)
                    .option("dbtable", "(select partition_columns from metainfo.metatables where tablename='finance.xx_gl_forecast') as colsPrecision")
                    .option("user", metaUserName)
                    .option("password", metaPassword)
                    .load()
```

I am trying to move the partition columns: `source_system_name, period_year` to the end of the dataFrame: `yearDF` because the columns that are used in Hive dynamic partitioning should be at the end.
To do that, I came up with the following logic:

```
val partition_columns      = spColsDF.select("partition_columns").collect().map(_.getString(0)).toSeq
val allColsOrdered         = yearDF.columns.diff(partition_columns) ++ partition_columns
val allCols                = allColsOrdered.map(coln => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(coln))
val resultDF               = yearDF.select(allCols:_*)
```

When I execute the code, I get the exception:`org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException` as below:

```
Exception in thread "main" 18/08/28 18:09:30 WARN Utils: Truncated the string representation of a plan since it was too large. This behavior can be adjusted by setting 'spark.debug.maxToStringFields' in SparkEnv.conf.
org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException: cannot resolve '`source_system_name,period_year`' given input columns: [cost_center, period_num, period_name, currencies, cc_channel, scenario, xx_pk_id, period_year, cc_region, reference_code, source_system_name, source_record_type, xx_last_update_tms, xx_last_update_log_id, book_type, cc_function, product_line, ptd_balance_text, project, ledger_id, currency_code, xx_data_hash_id, qtd_balance_text, pl_market, version, qtd_balance, period, ptd_balance, ytd_balance_text, xx_hvr_last_upd_tms, geography, year, del_flag, trading_partner, ytd_balance, xx_data_hash_code, xx_creation_tms, forecast_id, drm_org, account, business_unit, gl_source_name, gl_source_system_name];;
'Project [forecast_id#26L, period_year#27, period_num#28, period_name#29, drm_org#30, ledger_id#31L, currency_code#32, source_system_name#33, source_record_type#34, gl_source_name#35, gl_source_system_name#36, year#37, period#38, scenario#39, version#40, currencies#41, business_unit#42, account#43, trading_partner#44, cost_center#45, geography#46, project#47, reference_code#48, product_line#49, ... 20 more fields]
+- Relation[forecast_id#26L,period_year#27,period_num#28,period_name#29,drm_org#30,ledger_id#31L,currency_code#32,source_system_name#33,source_record_type#34,gl_source_name#35,gl_source_system_name#36,year#37,period#38,scenario#39,version#40,currencies#41,business_unit#42,account#43,trading_partner#44,cost_center#45,geography#46,project#47,reference_code#48,product_line#49,... 19 more fields] JDBCRelation((select forecast_id,period_year,period_num,period_name,drm_org,ledger_id,currency_code,source_system_name,source_record_type,gl_source_name,gl_source_system_name,year,period,scenario,version,currencies,business_unit,account,trading_partner,cost_center,geography,project,reference_code,product_line,book_type,cc_region,cc_channel,cc_function,pl_market,ptd_balance,qtd_balance,ytd_balance,xx_hvr_last_upd_tms,xx_creation_tms,xx_last_update_tms,xx_last_update_log_id,xx_data_hash_code,xx_data_hash_id,xx_pk_id,null::integer as del_flag,ptd_balance::character varying as ptd_balance_text,qtd_balance::character varying as qtd_balance_text,ytd_balance::character varying as ytd_balance_text from analytics.xx_gl_forecast where period_year='2017') as year2017) [numPartitions=1]
```

But if I pass the same column names in another way as following, the code works fine:

```
val lastCols        = Seq("source_system_name","period_year")
val allColsOrdered  = yearDF.columns.diff(lastCols) ++ lastCols
val allCols         = allColsOrdered.map(coln => org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col(coln))
val resultDF        = yearDF.select(allCols:_*)
```

Could anyone tell me what is the mistake I am doing here ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the error:

> ```
> cannot resolve '`source_system_name,period_year`
> ```

It means that, the following line:

```
spColsDF.select("partition_columns").collect().map(_.getString(0)).toSeq
```

is returning something like:

```
Array("source_system_name,period_year")
```

that means that both the column names are concatenated and form the first element of the array instead of seperate elements like you want.

To get the desired result, you need to split it on `,`. For eg, the following should work.

```
spColsDf.select("partition_columns").collect.flatMap(_.getAs[String](0).split(","))
```